# carregar uma div com uma pagina em php

Tags: php

Estou com um erro, vamos dizer, primário kkkk

Tenho uma pagina feita em html atualizada por php.

Meu problema esta para carregar o conteúdo de uma div.

Tenho um texto. Ao clicar nesse texto ele carrega o conteúdo em uma div, só que este conteúdo é uma pagina php, por exemplo `teste.php`.

A pergunta é.... Como fazer isso?

OBS.:tenho um arquivo,abaixo (`regras.php`)

```html
<?php  switch($_GET["pagina"])
 {  
  case  "adestraBasic":
  $var_conteudo="AdestraBasic.php";
  break; 
  case  "advance":
  $var_conteudo="Advance.php";
  break; 
  
     default: $var_conteudo="AdestraBasic.php";
  
 }
?>
```

E na página tenho:

```html
<?php include "regras.php";?>
```

A div:

```html
<div id="PHP">
    <?php include $var_conteudo; ?>
</div>
```

Página:

```html
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
 
 <div id="page">
  <div id="page-bgtop">
   <div id="page-bgbtm">
    <div id="content">
     <div class="post">
      <h2 class="title">curso da iron dog</h2>


<div id="PHP">
   <?php include $var_conteudo; ?>
        </div>

     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #content -->
    <div id="sidebar">
     <ul>
       <li> </li>
      
      <li>
             <h2>Cursos</h2>
       <ul>
 <li><a href="#">1 Adestramento Basico</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">2 Adestramento Avançado</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">3 Agility</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">4 Cães de Policia</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">5 Figurante</a></li>
        
       </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
              </div>
    <!-- end #sidebar -->
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- end #page -->
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que passar via GET o nome da  página que você quer que o 'regras.php' receba.

Eu uso a seguinte estrutura pra fazer isso.

Página principal:

```
<?php

//Usuários
$pagina['AdestraBasic'] = "adestra_basic.php";

//Se a variável 'link' for diferente de vazio.
if (isset($_GET["pag"])) 
{
    $link = $_GET["pag"];

    //Se o arquivo da página existir inclui.
    if (file_exists($pagina[$link]))
    {
        include_once $pagina[$link];
    }
    else
    {
        //die (include_once '../includes/pagina_erro.php');
    }
}
//Caso contrário inclui a página 'home'.
else 
{
    //include_once 'home.php';
}
```

?>

curso da iron dog

- 
- ### Cursos

  - 1 Adestramento Basico
  - 2 Adestramento Avançado
  - 3 Agility
  - 4 Cães de Policia
  - 5 Figurante

```
<!-- end #page -->
```

Página Adestra Básico:

```
<?
echo 'Incluiu página adestramento básico!!!';
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço o seguinte, recebo o nome da página por GET, e o nome original dos arquivos são os mesmos que os possíveis GETs. Fica bem básico para incluir a pagina:

```
$pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
//Faz uma validação do link aqui
...


Chama a página no lugar que você quiser
<?php include $pagina . ".php" ?>
```